# JavaFX Category Axis for XYChart is not in data order

Tags: javafx-2

I have a problem where when I add data to a category axis and the axis titles have been used before, the order gets screwed up.  Run the simple app below and click twice on the graph and look at the x axis to see what I mean. The data is supplied to the graph from month 0 to 10 but displayed in another order. Any Help?

```
package testCategoryBug;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class TestCategoryBug extends Application {
    static Boolean even=true;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Test Category Bug");    
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Month");       

        final LineChart<String,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis, yAxis);       
        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");     

        // Initialize some data for plotting.
        final Series<String, Number> plottablePairs  = new Series<String, Number>();
        final Series<String, Number> plottablePairs2 = new Series<String, Number>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Data<String,Number> pair= new Data<String,Number>("Month "+i,10.0*i);
            plottablePairs.getData().add(pair);
        }
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            Data<String,Number> pair= new Data<String,Number>("Month "+i,100.0-10*i);
            plottablePairs2.getData().add(pair);
        }

        // add the first of the series
        final ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> chartData=FXCollections.observableArrayList();;
        chartData.add(plottablePairs);
        lineChart.setData(chartData);

        // now on a mouse click, swap the data.  Click twice and see what happens
        lineChart.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                chartData.clear();
                if (even) {
                    chartData.add(plottablePairs2);
                } else {
                    chartData.add(plottablePairs);
                    // note that after this, the axis is screwed up.
                }
                lineChart.setData(chartData);
                even=!even;
            }
        });

        // Put up the scene
        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [I answered something similar here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21410404/2855515).  I haven't tried it with your code but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using [FX8 developers version](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html). You may want to upgrade.

There were few issues with chart's axis ordering, like [RT-23094](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23094), but they all were fixed in FX8.

Comment: if this is a product for sale than this is NOT a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. No matter how I setup the plot the ordering would always get messed up by reploting with new datapoints. The only fix was using java 1.8.

This was with the latest fx at the time, 2.2.51-b13. had to go with fx8 early access release.